# PHP pagination POST data resetting on page click

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passwd, $dbName);
  $whereClauses = array(); 
  if (! empty($_POST['user'])) $whereClauses[] ="type='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user'])."'"; 
  if (! empty($_POST['city'])) $whereClauses[] ="area='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['city'])."'"; 
  $where = ''; 
  if (count($whereClauses) > 0) { $where = ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$whereClauses); }
  
$page=$_GET["page"];
if($page == "" || $page == "1"){
$page1=0;
}
else{
$page1=($page*2)-2;
}

 if (! empty($_POST['order'])) {$query = "SELECT * FROM House ".$where."ORDER BY ".$_POST['order']." LIMIT $page1,2 "; }
else{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM House ".$where." LIMIT $page1,2"; 
}

  $row = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
  echo "<div id='product'>";
  while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($row)){
  $houseid = $data['houseId'];
  $titleid = $data['title'];
  $numberid = $data['number'];
  $streetid = $data['street'];
  $postcodeid = $data['postcode'];
  $areaid = $data['area'];
  $desid = $data['description'];
  $bedid = $data['bed'];
  $bathroomid = $data['bathroom'];
  $rateid = $data['rate'];
  $typeid = $data['type'];  
  
  echo"
<div id='single'>

$query1 = "SELECT imageId,name,alt From Image Where houseId = '$houseid'";
  if ( !($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1)) ) {
      die('<p>Error reading database</p></body></html>');
   }
  if ($result->num_rows){
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo 
  '<a href="view.php?viewid='. $houseid .'">
  <img src="getimg.php?id=' . $row1['imageId'] . '" width=200 height=200 alt="' . $row1['alt'] . '" title="' . $row1['name']  .'"/>
  </a>';
   }
 
echo"
</div>
</div>
";}


$query3 = "SELECT * FROM House ".$where."";
$res2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query3);
$count = $res2->num_rows;
$a=$count/2;
$a=ceil($a);
for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++)
{
?><a href="search.php?page=<?php echo $b;?>"style="text-decoration:none"> <?php echo $b. " ";?></a><?php
}

?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hi, the problem is that the page links don't work it resets if i click any of them and ends up displaying all the products.
I post data to this page from another form on a different page.

I tried this !isset($_SESSION['first_run'])) but that didn't let me use a new search criteria as the old one wouldnt go away.

Comment: Wait... are you trying to reuse $_POST-variables through clicks on <a>-tags (links)? Seriously? Either use $_GET-variables, which can be added to the URL-string, or lose the <a>-tags and use buttons (forms) and hidden $_POST-variables.

Comment: Thanks, i added get variables to the links and it works perfectly